# How to call methods with a "params" parameter from within a view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The definition of my extension method is this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static Boolean MatchRoute(this HtmlHelper Html, 
                                     BaseViewModel   Model, 
                                     String          ControllerName, 
                                     params          String[] ActionNames)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and this is how it's being used inside my view

```
<li class="questions <% = Html.GetSelectedClass(Model, "questions", "viewquestion", "index") %>">
```

but for some strange reason when the method is called only the first of the 2 paremeters for `ActionNames` is passed to the method. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea but this should work. What you have shown is in your view a call to `Html.GetSelectedClass` and in your extension method is called `MatchRoute` and returns boolean instead of string. Also if your views are strongly typed you don't need to pass a model, you could do this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetSelectedClass(
        this HtmlHelper<BaseViewModel> html, 
        string controllerName, 
        params string[] actionNames
    )
    {
        BaseViewModel model = html.ViewData.Model
        ...
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.GetSelectedClass("questions", "viewquestion", "index") %>
```